# SimpleXMLElement value to int

Tags: php, simplexml

I have problem with SimpleXMLElement.
This is var_dump one of my SimpleXML position:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#42 (4) 
{ 
    ["nazwa_waluty"] => string(14) "rubel rosyjski" 
    ["przelicznik"]  => string(1)  "1" 
    ["kod_waluty"]   => string(3)  "RUB" 
    ["kurs_sredni"]  => string(6)  "0,0514" 
}
```

and I don't know how to get "kurs_sredni" as an intiger.
I tried `(int) $position->kurs_sredni` but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:
This is my method. I would like to get "kurs_sredni" as a float:

```
public function getExchangeRate($currency)
    {
        $filename = 'LastA.xml';
        $filepath = Mage::getBaseDir('base') . '/media/exchangerate/' . $filename;
        $exchangeRateXml = simplexml_load_file($filepath);

        foreach($exchangeRateXml->pozycja as $position){
            if ($position->kod_waluty == $currency) {
                var_dump((float) $position->kurs_sredni);die();
            }
        }
    }
```

and var_dump returns 0

Comment: `kurs_sredni` as integer is 0. Maybe you mean ‘as float’ (as number)?

Comment: @fusion3k you're right, but (float) $position->kurs_sredni also returs 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with the string is that it is in european format, using comma as decimal separator instead of point.

So, you have first to replace `,` with `.`

```
$num = floatval( str_replace( ',','.', $position->kurs_sredni ) );
```

Comment: Exactly that was problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of exactly all that you've tried because there's no posted code but from looking at your post you might have messed up:

```
$NewVariableName= (int) $StringVariableThatNeedsToBeChanged;
echo $NewVariableName; //This is the new variable as an integer
```

You need to create a new variable that's going to take place being a new integer value.

Comment: post some actual code that you have trouble shooted with